# how to pass data from one controller's action to another controller's action in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a custom controller in my module and i want to pass data from one controller's action to another controller's action, but how can i do it may know the proper syntax ?

```
$params = array('order_ids' => $ids);
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/OrderController/pdfinvoices', array('_query' => $params));
```

I am trying this is it possible in magento?

Answer (score 1):

you can implement this by using following syntax.

1) Redirecting controller's action.

```
public function sayHelloAction() {
        $params = array('order_ids' => $ids);
        $this->_redirect('demo/tester/sayDemo', array('_query' => $params));
    }
```

2) Redirected controller.

```
public function sayDemoAction() {
        $para = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($para);
        echo "Hello World Tester!";
        exit;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this is great for direct redirection, but how can this be implemented if the first controller is responsible for a form and the other gets data from that form ? kinda like `edit` and `save`. is it possible via a hidden field or can it be simpler ?