# how to pass data from one action to another, with a form in between?

Tags: magento2, admin, controllers, forms, data

I found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117526/51034) a way to do a direct passing of data (magento 1) but what if the first controller serves a BO form and then the other controller gets the data,  kinda like `edit` and `save` of customer module.

I'm currently trying this approche:

1. overriding `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProvider`
2. modifying meta of said form `$this->meta = $this->modifyMeta($this->meta);`
3. in `modifyMeta()` do this:

   ```
   //adding my field to be processed in the save controller (BO)
   $meta['customer']['children']['my_field']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
       'formElement'   => 'input',
       'componentType' => 'field',
       'visible'       => '0',
       'value'         => 'my value'
   ];
   ```

But in the processing controller, the param is not retrieved with `$this->getRequest()->getParam('my_field')` (I get a big fat NULL)

if there's maybe a better way, please advise.